# Summarizing a watermains layer to show pipe footage in miles for each material type and the percentage of each type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, water, summary

I have a water mains layer with a pipe material field and length field. I need to summarize this layer broken down into the length of each type of pipe material in miles. Currently, everything is in feet. I also need the percentage of the lengths for each material. What is a quick and easy way to go about doing this?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to run a Dissolve, using the Material Type as the Dissolve field.

You can then Sum the length field in the Statistics part of the Dissolve Tool.

Once the Dissolve is complete, you can then use the field calculator to convert the summed length in feet to miles. I think the conversion is multiplying feet by 0.000189394 to get the total distance in miles.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try

Comment: This worked. Thank you!